# pandas dataframe: select multiple rows based on entries in other rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Update based on comments (2018/11/06):

Here is the actual .csv file that I am working with (slightly expanded from original post).  Assuming I cannot change the format of the .csv file, how can I

(a) Get an array of the students and scores that took "Test 1"?

(b) Restructure the data to make it easier to acquire (a)

```
Year,2017
Class,A
Test,1
Bob,71
Cathy,72
,
Test,2
Steve,73
Janet,74
,
,
Class,B
Test,1
Jim,75
Pam,76
,
Test,2
Linus,77
Lucy,78
,
,
,
Year,2018
Class,A
Test,1
Charles,79
Cindy,80
,
Test,2
Stanley,81
Kari,82
,
,
Class,B
Test,1
Duke,83
Amy,84
,
Test,2
Craig,85
Valerie,86
```

### ----------------------------------------------------------------

Original post:

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['Class A'],['Test 1'],['Bob',87],['Cathy',88],['Test 2'],['Steve',82],['Janet',81],['Class B'],['Test 1'],['Jim',92],['Pam',95],['Test 2'],['Linus',73],['Lucy',70]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Which yeilds

```
          0     1
0   Class A   NaN
1    Test 1   NaN
2       Bob  87.0
3     Cathy  88.0
4    Test 2   NaN
5     Steve  82.0
6     Janet  81.0
7   Class B   NaN
8    Test 1   NaN
9       Jim  92.0
10      Pam  95.0
11   Test 2   NaN
12    Linus  73.0
13     Lucy  70.0
```

Is there a way to select the scores received by students from both classes that took Test 1?  i.e.,

```
Bob  87.0
Cathy  88.0
Jim  92.0
Pam  95.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. IMO, the structure of your dataset does not fit to that what you probably intended. Column 0 is filled with several values of different meaning, like `Class A`, `Test 1` and `Bob`. The data you show here needs four columns or a multi index.

Comment: Unfortunately, the sample dataframe provided is a representation of a larger scientific data set that I am working with, so I do not have the liberty to change the structure

Comment: Understood - however: data analysis begins with importing and bringing into a suitable shape. So would you please show us how your actual data source looks like? I'd be really interested in how it is structured and what you could do for your advantage while importing.

Comment: Actual data structure provided (.csv format).

Comment: Ok, this is a really sad example of a data file, which on top was without reason named csv  - I feel with you. I'd like to state that I would not suppose such a file to originate from a _scientific_ background - seriously, without meaning to offend anyone. However, that said, I'll have a look at it...

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** *Importing the data from the given source-file to a structured dataframe in order to be able to have access to convenient analysis functions:*

The idea is to iterate over the lines of the textfile.
  - I assume that each line consists of two comma separated strings.
  - Each line which has a first string which is one of "Year", "Class" and "Test" is only used to update a dict which holds the current set of these three values.
  - all other lines are used to append their data together with Year, Class and Test info to a list `data`.
  - except those lines where the first string is the empty string.

```
with open('no_csv.txt', 'r') as f:
    Idx = {'Year': None, 'Class': None, 'Test': None}
    data = []
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split(',')
        if key in Idx.keys():
            Idx[key] = value
        elif key != '':
            data.append(list(Idx.values()) + [key, value])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Year', 'Class', 'Test', 'Name', 'Points'])


df

    Year Class Test     Name Points
0   2017     A    1      Bob     71
1   2017     A    1    Cathy     72
2   2017     A    2    Steve     73
3   2017     A    2    Janet     74
4   2017     B    1      Jim     75
5   2017     B    1      Pam     76
6   2017     B    2    Linus     77
7   2017     B    2     Lucy     78
8   2018     A    1  Charles     79
9   2018     A    1    Cindy     80
10  2018     A    2  Stanley     81
11  2018     A    2     Kari     82
12  2018     B    1     Duke     83
13  2018     B    1      Amy     84
14  2018     B    2    Craig     85
15  2018     B    2  Valerie     86
```

Please note that this code relies on ordered keys in the dictionary, which is implemented in normal `dict`s from Python 3.7 on. To gurantee this in Python 3.6 or below, one should use an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
Idx = OrderedDict(Year=None, Class=None, Test=None)
```

---

**Restructuring for better handling**

I'd suggest to restructure your dataframe. If you strictly define meanings of columns, you'd get e.g. to sth like this:

```
data = [
['Class A', 'Test 1', 'Bob', 87],
['Class A', 'Test 1', 'Cathy', 88],
['Class A', 'Test 2', 'Steve', 82],
['Class A', 'Test 2', 'Janet', 81],
['Class B', 'Test 1', 'Jim', 92],
['Class B', 'Test 1', 'Pam', 95],
['Class B', 'Test 2', 'Linus', 73],
['Class B', 'Test 2', 'Lucy', 70]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

         0       1      2   3
0  Class A  Test 1    Bob  87
1  Class A  Test 1  Cathy  88
2  Class A  Test 2  Steve  82
3  Class A  Test 2  Janet  81
4  Class B  Test 1    Jim  92
5  Class B  Test 1    Pam  95
6  Class B  Test 2  Linus  73
7  Class B  Test 2   Lucy  70
```

Having this structure in your dataframe, you simply can ask for all rows, where the Test-column is `Test 1`:

```
df[df[1]=='Test 1']

         0       1      2   3
0  Class A  Test 1    Bob  87
1  Class A  Test 1  Cathy  88
4  Class B  Test 1    Jim  92
5  Class B  Test 1    Pam  95
```

**Slimmer data by using column names**

And as pandas dataframes may have column names, you can even make it better readable and with less redundant data by giving your columns a meaningful name, describing the data which is stored within them:

```
data = [
['A', 1, 'Bob', 87],
['A', 1, 'Cathy', 88],
['A', 2, 'Steve', 82],
['A', 2, 'Janet', 81],
['B', 1, 'Jim', 92],
['B', 1, 'Pam', 95],
['B', 2, 'Linus', 73],
['B', 2, 'Lucy', 70]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Class', 'Test', 'Name', 'Points'])

df[df.Test==1]

  Class  Test   Name  Points
0     A     1    Bob      87
1     A     1  Cathy      88
4     B     1    Jim      92
5     B     1    Pam      95
```

**What you gain for further analysis by doing so...**

Data structured like this opens access to very convenient pandas functions for the next obvious questions you'll perhaps like to answer, e.g.:

*What was the average score per Class per Test?*

```
df.groupby(['Class', 'Test']).mean()

            Points
Class Test        
A     1       87.5
      2       81.5
B     1       93.5
      2       71.5
```

*Who was the best one per Class per Test?*

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['Class', 'Test']).Points.idxmax()]

  Class  Test   Name  Points
1     A     1  Cathy      88
2     A     2  Steve      82
5     B     1    Pam      95
6     B     2  Linus      73
```

Comment: Just as a comment to the OP: This is sometimes referred to as `tidy data`, and is definitely the preferred way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; unfortunately, the sample dataframe provided is a representation of a larger scientific data set that I am working with, so I do not have the liberty to change the structure.

Answer (score 1):

Try for instance:

```
df[~df[1].isnull()]

0   1
2   Bob     87.0
3   Cathy   88.0
5   Steve   82.0
6   Janet   81.0
9   Jim     92.0
10  Pam     95.0
12  Linus   73.0
13  Lucy    70.0
```

This gives you all students and their results. Now, to do the subsetting, we need to get the index for when the test B data starts. To do this, do the following:

```
df[(df[0]=="Class B")].index
```

which will tell you `7`. That means, all students with an index number larger than 7 are in class B, and smaller than 7 are in class A. Similarly, you can subset to get at the rows for Test 1 and Test 2. Following this logic, we can do the following (though this became uglier than I anticipated...):

```
students = df[~df[1].isnull()].index
classdiv = df[(df[0]=="Class B")].index[0]
classA = df.loc[range(0,classdiv)]
classB = df.loc[range(classdiv, len(df))]
ATestDiv = classA[classA[0]=="Test 2"].index[0]
BTestDiv = classB[classB[0]=="Test 2"].index[0]

Test1 = [ind for ind in students if ind < classdiv and ind < ATestDiv] + \
        [ind for ind in students if ind > classdiv and ind < BTestDiv]

df.iloc[Test1]
    0   1
2   Bob     87.0
3   Cathy   88.0
9   Jim     92.0
10  Pam     95.0
```